# Does tSQLT needed the database should set TRUSTWORTHY ON?

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, ssms, clr, tsqlt

Is database `TRUSTWORTHY ON` necessary for tSQLt to run? In our DB environment, we can't set TRUSTWORTHY ON for databases.
Does tSqlt run with the database status of TRUSTWORTHY OFF?

Comment: Did you perform any kind of search on this topic? Did you see this previous StackOverflow question, [tSQLt TRUSTWORTHY and CLR requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530190/tsqlt-trustworthy-and-clr-requirement)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tSQLt TRUSTWORTHY and CLR requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530190/tsqlt-trustworthy-and-clr-requirement)